# Getting Error while running PL/SQL program

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
declare 
numbers department.dpt_no%type ;
cursor sc is
 select dpt_no into numbers from department ;
begin
open sc;
loop sc
fetch sc into numbers;
dbms_output.put_line('department numbers is'||numbers);
end loop;
close sc;
end;
```

While executing above program it showing error like

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "FETCH" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

whats the wrong in my code please let me know

Comment: I believe this query has been addressed earlier. Plz refer older posts for this. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you're not supposed to be doing `LOOP SC`

Additionally, you need to check for `NOTFOUND` when doing a `FETCH`

Try:

```
loop
    fetch sc into numbers;
    exit when sc%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('department numbers is'||numbers);
end loop;
```

See the [LOOP documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/loop_statement.htm#LNPLS01328)

If you for whatever reason actually wanted a label on your loop, you'd use this syntax:

[image]

Comment: This "solution" reproduces the other bloomer in the OP's code: no exit condition.  So the program will hurl an exception when you run out of rows in DEPARTMENT

Comment: Fair enough. OP was only asking about a syntax error, though.

Comment: @ram Read APCs comment; it's probably that.

Comment: How to reduce my problem?

Comment: @ram I've added an exit condition which is what APC was pointing out as an additional error.

Comment: Your answer is giving in some repeating values,i tried like loop
    `fetch sc into numbers;
    dbms_output.put_line('department numbers is'||numbers);
exit when sc%notfound;
end loop;` it giving perfect result

Comment: The `exit` should be before you do anything else in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the "sc" after loop.

```
open sc;
loop
   fetch sc into numbers;
   exit when sc%notfound;
   dbms_output.put_line('department numbers is'||numbers);
end loop;
```